# setting ImageView from image stored in sdcard in higher version of android not working

Tags: android, file, bitmap, imageview

```
Toast.makeText(this, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
    "/whatsupv2/abc.jpg");

Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

the above code is working for android 3.3 but not in 4.1.2 where we have two storage directories... i have checked abc.jpg is there in dir .. and path given is correct.. but imageview just show a white screen..

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am facing same problems.

Answer (score 0):

> but not in 4.1.2 where we have two storage directoies

There is only one external storage directory in all Android devices, at least through Android 4.3.

First, make sure the image is in the official external storage location.

Second, use `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/whatsupv2/abc.jpg")` rather than string concatenation.

Third, either use `decodeFile()` *or* `setImageURI()`, not both.

Fourth, examine LogCat for any messages.